# sunspot parameters transferring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot

I have a little problem with the sunspot. I have a model with fields

```
:country_id
:city_id
```

both are integers. And

```
:title
```

is string

I have, in model.rb

```
searchable do
    text :title
    integer :country_id
    integer :city_id
  end
```

and

```
@search = Page.solr_search do
      fulltext params[:title]
      with(:country_id,params[:country_id])
      with(:city_id,params[:city_id])

    end
```

in controller.

But sunspot don't want to work, it work only without

```
          with(:country_id,params[:country_id])
          with(:city_id,params[:city_id])
```

params[:city_id] and params[:country_id] are passed correctly, so problem is not with them.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an error or is it just returning no results?  Is the title parameter correct?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sunspot don't want to work'? Does it break, or just not returning any results? Did u do the re-index after defining `searchable` block? Are you sure you have Page instances with the criteria you are searching (title, country_id, city_id)? Please give more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration seems good to me, do a re-indexing and try following,

```
   @search = Page.solr_search do
      fulltext params[:title]
      with :country_id, params[:country_id].to_i
      with :city_id, params[:city_id].to_i    
    end
```